# Completion for Hadoop command in zsh

Tags: linux, hadoop, zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I love the tab completion feature in zsh. 
But when I use hadoop command, it seems do not work anymore. 
So is there any idea to auto-completion for hadoop command in zsh?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you added Hadoop_Home to PATH ?

Comment: I've already done. `export HADOOP_HOME=/home/my_user_name/app/hadoop-client/hadoop`

Comment: But have you added this to PATH? it's good to edit your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file and add the following to the end: `export HADOOP_HOME="/home/amar/Work/hadoop-1.0.4/bin/"
export PATH="$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH"`